# 2 wordpress blogs with 1 users table and 1 login

Tags: login, directory, cookies, shared-user-tables

I have been trying to achieve that and I did without the 1 login part

I fallowed this [post/tutorial](http://nokeywordinurl.com/2-wordpress-blogs-with-1-users-table-and-1-login/) , but no matter what I do I can not get it to login ones for both websites.

My set up is `sitename.com/wordpress1/` and `sitename.com/wordpress2/`(in this one I have `BuddyPress` installation)

The shared user table work - I can register from wordpress1 site and login with the same username on wordpress2 without any problems, but I need to login for every site separately.

I can see that after I login in the two websites they create 2 different cookies for each:

```
name: wordpress_38f490d1cc4aa19b4d792ab9d875aaeb
name: wordpress_logged_in_38f490d1cc4aa19b4d792ab9d875aaeb

name: wordpress_8c8848dc05bf5a0a44af5ccc0204cd82
name: wordpress_logged_in_8c8848dc05bf5a0a44af5ccc0204cd82

host: sitename.com //for all of the above.
```

My understanding is that the two should create only one and use it across.

What do you thing the problem could be? Am I missing something in the settings? Could the problem be in my HOST provider? What about the `.htaccess`?

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
From [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network) I read this:

> If you plan on creating sites that are strongly interconnected, that share data, or **share users**, then a multisite network might not be the best solution.

So I chose to use multiple installations instead...

Comment: Why do you not use multisite? I've dealt with plenty of multisite installs and never had to deal with any of these problems

Comment: please read my EDIT

Comment: I'm sorry but it's advising multisite vs single site, not multisite vs 2 singlesites with a mishmashed user table.

Comment: If shared users is all you want to share, then use multisite. Right now install A has no way of getting posts from install B. In multisite there are APIs for this. Also take whatever the codex says with a pinch of salt, it's not always upto date and current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install wordpress at sitename.com
- Setup multisite
- Create a new site at /wordpress1/
- Create a new site at /wordpress2/
- Install Buddypress plugin
- Activate buddypress on /wordpress2/ ( not network wide, just wordpress2 )
- Hey presto you have exactly what you want without the nightmarish usertable situation

Problems you will face with the login using a shared user table:

- The usertable isn't the only shared table
- Roles and capabilities are intimately tied into the usertable, you now have 2 of these, where there should only be 1
- Upgrading everything will be a maintenance nightmare
- A lot of plugins will hate the setup you want

All of this is avoided by using multisite